# How to pass variables to Sessions rather than to the URL - PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

```
<a class='okok' id='$file' href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'>$file</a>
```

The above code is a link which passes its name to the variable 'file' which then gets displayed in the URL as:

http://example.com?file=thefile.html (whatever the file is)

Using PHP, I can now retrieve the variable from the URL and then process it (in this case the variable is 'thefile.html'.

How would I use Sessions to prevent variables from getting passed onto the URL. So instead of:

```
http://example.com?file=thefile.html
```

I would have:

```
http://example.com
```

And the variable 'thefile.html' would be stored in a Session.

If you need more info on what I am trying to ask, then please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to create a valid page for receiving the query string you're passing in the url
suppose the link you have is on index.html and your link destination is result.php, then you'd write the following code in result.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_GET["filename"]) ){
$fname = $_GET["filename"];
//code to deal with filename 

//save in session variable 
$_SESSION['UploadedFilename'] = $fname;
}
?>
<!-- html -->
<?php
session_write_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to pass the file name from the browser (where the link is) to the host without a parameter, you would need to use a cookie. Sessions are a host concept.

So, as a simple example, you could use:

```
<a class='okok' id='$file' href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "' onclick="document.cookie='filename=" . $file . "';">$file</a>
```

This creates a cookie with the filename in it.

On the host side, you retrieve the name with $_COOKIES['filename'].